# Проблема с установкой Valgrind

Tags: valgrind, mips

Система под которую компилирую Valgrind `mips`.
Система на img диске, которую монтирую в директорию `/mnt/mount_dir`. При конфигурации `valgrind` естественно задаю `--prefix=/mnt/mount_dir`, это путь до корня, потом `make` и `make install` Но при запуске уже на эмулированной системе `valgrind` ругается что не может найти `memchek`, конечно же, потому что ищет он в директории `/mnt/mount_dir/lib/valgrind/memcheck-mips32-linux`, а нужно в `/lib/valgrind/memcheck-mips32-linux` Какой префикс нужно ставить на этапе конфигурации, чтобы `valgrind` считал что `/mnt/mount_dir` это `/` корень?

Comment: Попробовал с помощью `chroot . /mnt/mount_dir` не выходит, так как система `busybox` и `/bin/bash` ему не найти `chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Гуглил целый день, но вменяемого ответа так и не нашёл. Колдовство с `--sysroot` и `--prefix` не помогло. Пробовал устанавливать различные флаги, большинство из которых просто не поддерживаются `vallgrind`. Решение проблемы в моём случае, это создание ссылки `/mnt/mount_dir` на корень `/`. Возможно есть более человеческое решение, но я его не нашёл.